# ActionBar custom style does not stay on rotation

Tags: android, rotation, android-actionbar, orientation, landscape

I have created a custom ActionBar style, and when it is in portrait it looks as intended. For some reason though, when you rotate the screen to landscape the style is not applied and everything on the style bar is applied to a bright white composition. I can not figure out why it is doing this. There are no orientation differences and I have poked around in the documentation as well as Stack Over Flow in order to find something, but honestly I can't find much. 
This is what my custom code looks like for my Action Bar and it works great in portrait.

```
    <style name="Theme.Custom" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/defaultTextColor</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:icon">@drawable/icon_trans</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/header</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBar.Text</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Text" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/defaultTextColor</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Where is this style contained? res/values/styles.xml? And/or is there a res/values-land/styles.xml

Comment: res/values/styles. Though the styles we use work for both layout and layout-land. Plus I've already exasperated that option and tried putting in the folder values-land and still the same old problem unfortunately. PS Thanks for reply.

Comment: where is the android:theme tag being applied? in the whole app or just one activity?

Comment: The manifest references Theme.Custom for the style of the entire application.

Comment: I'm sorry, for the theme of the Action Bar, for the entire application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using an XML file to define a gradient for my ActionBar and I did not place the xml file in the "drawable-land". Android will obviously not apply a style that is not there. Copying over the XML worked like a charm. So thank you for those who attempted to help!